# Equivalence between algebraic statements and geometric relations.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm currently trying to read a geometry and symmetry book and came across a little problem that I am having difficulty understanding.
I need to show that if xm=mx then the point X is on the line M, and also that if xa=ax, then the point X is on the plane A.

Note that x is the inversion through the point X and m is the reflection across the mirror M.

Super stuck. Any insight or suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to guess what you mean. Can you give details about where you found this and what sort of algebraic structure you are working in when you say "xm"?

Comment: What is $x$? What is $m$? Where does the point $X$ lie (is it in $\mathbb{R}^3$?)

Comment: What does $xm$ mean? This seems like a badly underspecified question.

Comment: It seems like points $X$, lines $M$ and planes $A$ are *associated* to some elements $x,m,a$ in some algebraic structure. But I think we have no clue *how* and which alg.structure..

Comment: I edited my question, now that I figured out what little x and m were. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Good. Have you figured out what $a$ is, in $xa=ax$?

Comment: Not really, I am having a difficult time with this question in general. But any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to compare functions is by applying them to something. Given that there is only one point in the problem statement, it is reasonable to apply the function to $x$. At this point, the weakness of your notation becomes a big nuisance, so let us call $r_x$ the reflection with respect to the point $x$ and $r_m$ the reflection with respect to the line/plane $m$.

Now $x$ is the unique fixed point of $r_x$.

So, if $r_x\circ r_m = r_m \circ r_x$, then $r_x(r_m(x))=r_m(r_x(x))=r_m(x)$.

This implies that $r_m(x)$ is a fixed point of $r_x$, so $r_m(x)=x$. This implies that $x$ is a fixed point of $r_m$, so it has to be on the fixed line/plane $m$.